# Parsing arguments in python with any order

Tags: python, parsing, command-line

I am trying to parse command line arguments and I have never done it before. I have tried a few things. The code below is the last thing that I tried, but I received the error: "unrecognized arguments". I want to be able to put something like

```
copy-column-csv.py cname=Quiz source=source.csv target=target.csv out=out.csv
```

on the command line, but also have the ability to have it in any order. I am not sure how to go about this. Below is my code:

```
import argparse
import sys, re
import numpy as np
import smtplib
from random import randint
import csv
import math
import pandas as pd

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-cname')
parser.add_argument('-source')
parser.add_argument('-target')
parser.add_argument('-out')
args = parser.parse_args()


#col = sys.argv[1]
#source = sys.argv[2]
#target = sys.argv[3]
#newtarg = sys.argv[4]


sourceFile = pd.read_csv(source)
targetFile = pd.read_csv(target)
del targetFile[cname]
targetFile[col] = pd.Series(sourceFile[col])
targetFile.to_csv(out, index = False)
```

Comment: Try running your program as `copy-column-csv.py -cname=Quiz -source=source.csv -target=target.csv -out=out.csv`.  Note the `-` before the arguments.

Comment: Hi Kate, for future reference, try to make your question titles a little more specific -- a title that captures the question at hand. That way someone with the same issue will be able to search and find the provide answers. Something like "How do you parse arguments using ArgumentParser in python?" I hope you find what you're looking for!

Comment: @RocketHazmat Ahh okay. I see. Is there anyway you don't have to use the dash or is that necessary? Also, when I do this how to I refer to the arguments passed? For example for source, would it be args.source?

Comment: @DavyM oh okay I will. Sorry about that

Comment: @Kate If you want to use `argparse`, then *yes*, you *need* the dash.  Also, yes it would be `args.source`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming well formed arguments, you could split sys.argv up into a dictionary:

```
args_dict = {}
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    split = arg.split('=')
    args_dict[split[0]] = split[1]
```

args_dict will look like this:

```
{'cname': 'Quiz',
 'out': 'out.csv',
 'source': 'source.csv',
 'target': 'target.csv'}
```

And you can access the elements like so:

```
print args_dict['cname']
print args_dict['out']
print args_dict['source']
print args_dict['target']
```

Comment: Hmm okay I did not even think about creating a dictionary. I will try this! Thanks!

Comment: @Kate No problem! Upvote and mark as answer if it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I'm doing it.

```
from optparse import OptionParser
from optparse import OptionGroup

parser = OptionParser(usage)

required = OptionGroup(parser, "Required Arguments")
required.add_option("--genome", dest="genome_file", help="File representing genome. FASTA nucleotide format. ")
required.add_option("--anno", dest="anno_file", help="File containing genome annotation information in GTF/GFF3 format. ")
required.add_option("--output", dest="prefix", help="Creates a folder named with the supplied prefix containing output files. ")

parser.add_option_group(required)

if len(args) != 0 or not options.genome_file or not options.anno_file or not options.prefix:
    parser.error("Required arguments have not been supplied.  \n\t\tUse -h to get more information.")
    sys.exit()
```

You'll pass the arguments when you run it, for example, with --genome=myfile.txt, and in the code that value becomes options.genome_file.

Comment: Why `optparse` instead of `argparse`?

Comment: It's just what I use, just a personal preference.  Nothing wrong with argparse.

Comment: Note: [optparse has been deprecated](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html)